# How to replace standard DataGridRow with a custom DataGridRow in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I wish I could replace standard `DataGridRow` in a `DataGrid` with my custom version : `MyDataGridRow` .

```
public class MyDataGridRow : DataGridRow
{ ... }
```

I know I can replace the `Template` of standard `DataGridRow`, but I want to replace it entirely, as it opens plenty of options like introduction of new properties, events etc.

It should be possible, I think.

Your thoughts !

The question is more clear in comparison to possible duplicate : [How can I add Dependency Property to a DataGridRow WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104080/how-can-i-add-dependency-property-to-a-datagridrow-wpf) . My question title and question content is more helpful and more general. As before posting this question I searched a lot but couldnt find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add Dependency Property to a DataGridRow WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104080/how-can-i-add-dependency-property-to-a-datagridrow-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `DataGrid` and override its `GetContainerForItemOverride()` method to return the new `DataGridRowEx`.

```
    public class DataGridRowEx : DataGridRow
    {
       // you can add any custom dependency property here
    }

    public class DataGridEx : DataGrid
    {
       //...
       protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
       {
          return new DataGridRowEx();
       }
    }
```

Answer adapted from [How can I add Dependency Property to a DataGridRow WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104080/how-can-i-add-dependency-property-to-a-datagridrow-wpf)